# Why does the images index on Stack Overflow appear twice?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images

**Scenario**: I upload a picture when I post an answer or a question on a Stack Exchange community.

Why does it look like

`[![enter image description here][2]][2]`

instead of

`![enter image description here][2]`

?

Is it a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is definitely a feature. The second link markup causes the image to *be* a link. Take this image I've used before, for example:

[image: Image from a different question, hyperlinked.]

The markup used: `[![Image from a different question, hyperlinked.][1]][1]`

The above image uses the syntax you're questioning. Notice the underline below it. If you click this image, you will be taken to the image itself.

Without that syntax:

[image: Image from a different question, not hyperlinked.]

The markup used: `![Image from a different question, not hyperlinked.][1]`

Note how there is no underline, and you will not be taken anywhere by clicking the image. This is the syntax you proposed as correct.

Both *are* correct, the former method just has some more functionality to it.

Comment: Perhaps it is my browser, but I do not see an underline below the 1st image.  Both images render identically to me.  However, if I hover my mouse over the 1st image, I see a URL at the bottom of my screen and my cursor shape changes.

Comment: @toolic The difference is likely due to changes in the design of SO and Meta.SO since 2015, when this answer was written :).