# [![Does it need to be clickable?][1]][1]

Tags: support, markdown, images

To get an image to have a link to show the original size of an uploaded image, markdown of the form

```
[![image description here][1]][1]
```

is used.

However, *if an image fits in the available width for the question* (a "small image"),

```
![image description here][1]
```

apparently suffices.

Recently, I edited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59927303/revisions) in the review queue to expedite the acceptance of a useful suggested edit by changing the image markdown to the former as something to change, and left a comment for the editor regarding the format. They suggested that the latter format is better for small images.

[Why does the images index on Stack Overflow appear twice?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307073/1115360) informs us that

> Both are correct, the former method just has some more functionality to it.

With a small image, is there any *advantage* to the first markdown form? For example, there could be accessibility concerns that I am unaware of.

Comment: "***With a small image**, is there any advantage to the first markdown form?*" the bold is important. What if it *isn't* small? And it might be small on one monitor but not another. Unless you can distinguish between them categorically, then *maybe* you can remove the clickable-ness but...then it becomes inconsistent.

Comment: @VLAZ I thought I covered that in the first paragraph. However, I have emphasized that the question is concerned with small images.

Comment: Is it still "small" when you look at it on a phone? On mine the embedded image is *very slightly* smaller, so it's re-sized. It's still readable but if I expand it, I can see it bigger. It's probably something like 97% the size when embedded. So, this specific image is OK *on my phone*. Would it still look fine on every device? Moreover, on *my computer* that image takes up about half the width of the question. Since I'm on a vertical monitor, that's close to the minimum width for a desktop page. Were that image twice as wide - it'd fit on desktop but not on mobile.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm all for using the first form for consistency, but at least one other user (who no longer wishes their contributions to SO to be used, so I won't link) says "[it] creates a clickable link for no good reason."

Comment: I find consistency to be a good reason to have stuff. Other embedded images are clickable - this one isn't, so it's inconsistent. Consistency > "good", in my experience.

Comment: You can quote me on that. I regularly remove these links from images when they’re not something that needs to be easily blown up. It is annoying for things to be links that don’t need to be links. If necessary, there’s always “open image in new tab”.